# Hive Load data from Client Machine

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to write a standalone java file to connect to `hadoop` db with `HiveJDBC` in a windows machine and load data for table from a local csv file.

I'm getting on error `"Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:23 Invalid path 'd:/Sample2.txt': only "file" or "hdfs" file systems accepted".`

What i'm trying is right or wrong? Can we load data from client windows machine for `hadoop` db.

Comment: Did u find a solution for this.. i am facing the same problem now...help me if u find any way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use something like:

```
file:d:/Sample2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that the api accepts only file:// or hdfs://.

Check this question too - [How to make your mapper write on local file system in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898766/how-to-make-your-mapper-write-on-local-file-system-in-hadoop)